# Usage of self subclassResponsibility

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm new to Pharo and I'm having trouble grasping some concepts, specifically `subclassResponsibilty`.

I have the following objecttree:

```
AbstractDictionary
--TreeBasedDictionary (not abstract)
--AbstractArrayDictionary
----SimpleDictionary (not abstract)
----FastDictionary (not abstract)
```

All 3 implement the operations `at:put:` and `at:` (and more). I understood from class today that I can pull up `at:put:` to the `AbstractDictionary` with the following implementation:

```
at: thisKey put: thisValue
"insert new key / value pair"
^self 
    at: thisKey
    put: thisValue
    duplicate: [self error:'duplicate key']
```

Then I implemented a metod `at:put:duplicate:` in `TreeBasedDictionary  and AbstractArrayDictionary` (because the implementation is the same for the latter's subclasses). Then, when I call `at:put:` on an object it won't find it in the instance of either `TreeBasedDictionary , SimpleDictionary or FastDictionary`  but when looking up the tree it finds this method in the superclass (AbstractDictionary). This will then call self with `at:put:duplicate:` . This method is implemented by the 3 afore mentioned classes, and then the self which is pointing to the instance of the class that made the initial call is sent the message to execute `at:put:duplicate:`.

Now, `AbstractArrayDictionary,SimpleDictionary and FastDictionary` all have a method named `size`. Both classes at the bottom of the inheritence tree implement this method. `AbstractArrayDictionary` implements this method as follows

```
size
"dictionary size"
self subclassResponsibility
```

Suppose I implemented this method for my `TreeBasedDictionary`, I suppose I should implement the size method in my `AbstractDictionary` class as shown above.

My questions: Why do I need to do it like that, and not like this:

```
size
"dictionary size"
^self size
```

And if so, do I remove the method from `AbstractArrayDictionary` and why?

Comment: You are talking about `put:at:` and then use `at:put:` in the example. Also you have both `at:put:duplicate:` and `put:at:duplicate:`. Are you sure that you haven't done any mistakes?

Comment: Oh, that's a mistake indeed. Both are talking about the same method. I will correct this now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, look.

First of all if you use

```
size
  ^ self size
```

you'll end up in the infinite recursion. You ask `size` of object and the `size` method asks `size` of the object itself and so on.

Now in general about what you should know.

1. You should avoid duplication, that's why you are moving similar methods to the parent nodes in hierarchy. If you have a same method in all subclasses, move it into the superclass without hesitation.
2. You can just implement methods where they should work. E.i. not write methods with `self subclassResponsibility` at all. Objects should respond to messages that they can understand. Can *AbstractDictionary* put elements in it? No. Then there can be no method.
3. It's not nice to do things that I've written in #2 part. Because

   - when you browse *AbstractDictionary* class you get an idea that it should support `at:put:duplicate:`, but the functionality depends on the implementation (aka subclass).
   - when someone will be implementing another subclass of your dictionary, for example *MagicBagDictionary* and will forget to implement `at:put:duplicate:`, then during execution he will be gently reminded that this is a subclass responsibility and the method should be implemented. Otherwise he will get an error "message not understood by MagicBagDictionary".

Concerning the `size` method again: if you know at some point where you can get the size - do it. For example if *AbstractDictionary* has instance variable `container` that will hold all the element and should be able to tell the size of them - you can implement

```
size
  ^ container size
```

in the *AbstractDictionary*. But if you have no idea ho the element will be stored and how to calculate their size at that point, you should use:

```
size
  "dictionary size"
  self subclassResponsibility
```

This way *AbstractDictionary* is saying:

> yes, you can get my size, but I have no idea how to calculate it because I'm not complete. But my subclasses should know that, so don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Your explanation was nice and clear and made me understand this, thank you for that!  One remark though. When I put `size ^self size` in the superclass, it actually does call the method in the leaf class that made the initial call.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer, this means that you use `super size` form non `size` method of subclass. And it's a bad practice to call different method of superclass. Also if you think about this a bit more you can easily understand that this kind of implementation will generate a lot of WTFs per minute ;) I agree that we can make this work, but is this out goal?